# How to limit the number of rows displayed in a table?

Tags: birt

I have a Data Source, a Data Set and a Data Cube. The data cube has a group and a summary field with a count function.

In the report I have a table sorted by that summary field. This table has a lot of rows (~1000) but I only want to show the first 5.

How can I limit the number of rows displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both tables and cross-tables have a top N operator allowing to filter rows as your requirement. In your case this is a cross-table based on a datacube:

*Select the cross-tab -> filter tab -> Add -> Select your measure -> Operator "Top N" (or "Bottom N", depending on the sort direction of your crosstab)*

Please note this approach is much less efficient than grouping and filtering in a dataset query, if it is based on a database.
[image: Top N filter in a crosstab]