# BIRT limit bar graph on x-axis

Tags: reporting, birt, maximo

**Situation**
I have a BIRT report with a stacked bar graph which represents the costs per asset. The graph is based on a datacube. On the y-axis I have a sum of the costs (datacube measure). On the axis a group of the asset (since the dataset has multiple rows per asset) The option series grouping is the costtype group. I sorted the graph on the x-axis from high to low based on the cost. This works fine.

**Problem**
The problem is that my dataset is limited by a reportingperiod and can have a large number of assets. The report 'scales' the x-axis to fit them all. This squases everything, which looks bad and is almost unreadable. I want to limit the graph with the top 20 results.

**Tried**

**scripting**
 I can't find any option to do so. If I was using a crosstab I can use some scripting to 'count' the number of rows, but I don't know how to make BIRT stop drawing the table. For a graph I have no idea how to 'count' the number of x-axis entries plotted. Here I also don't see a way to stop BIRT drawing the graph.

**aggegation** I also tried to make somekind of runnig count on unique assets groups. I tested this by plotting my examples   (in the hope I got a straight line from 0,0 to 198,198 (the dataset now has 198 unique assets) I coulnd't get this, but if i could it should be possible to use a filter that checks if this running count is below a 20.

I simplefied the dataset a bit for this example. Doing a double query that first finds the top 20 and then uses that as a base to get additional info is not possible due to performance.

Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort AND limit data in a crosstab. Then just use the crosstab as source for the graph.

This works perfectly and is discribed in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29653715/1341373

Comment: So does that make this question a duplicate of the existing question?

Comment: no, because it's a two step solution. You won't find the option directly on the graph. You need to add a crosstab, limit it (and most likely hide it from your report)